# Can't write this simple line code in razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to write below simple code in razor page but it gives always error.

```
( @gallery.Images.Count images )   // expect : ( 23 images )
```

But strangely below code works

```
(@Model.RateCount rates)
```

I am getting compilation error not runtime exception

Full cshtml page is at below.

```
@using Something.UI.Models.ViewModels
@model List<ImageGalleryUI>
<div class="albumlist">
    @foreach (ImageGalleryUI gallery in Model)
    {

        <a href="@Html.ActionLinkRef(gallery.DisplayAction)">
            <img src="@gallery.AlbumImageSrc" alt="@gallery.AlbumName" width="150px"/>
        </a>
        @Html.ActionLink(gallery.DisplayAction) 
        ( @gallery.Images.Count images )
    }
</div>
```

And here is error

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Source Error:


Line 9:          </a>
Line 10:         @Html.ActionLink(gallery.DisplayAction) 
Line 11:         ( @{gallery.Images.Count} images )
Line 12:     }
Line 13: </div>
```

Comment: Please post more of your razor code

Comment: Only missing the exception now, and we will be on our way :)

Comment: AnyOne - See my edit to my answer. That should resolve the issue for you.

Comment: provide the fragment of code where you define gallery and the compilation error ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't done anything like this at the top

```
@{
   gallery = new ...
}
```

Then gallery does not exist.

Are you sure you do not mean `@Model.gallery.Images.Count` ?

**EDIT**

Try replacing

```
( @gallery.Images.Count images )
```

With

```
@: ( @gallery.Images.Count images )
```

Should work out just fine. Problem is that Razor is interpreting ( as part of the code, and not as part of the output. Put @: to let Razor know that what comes on this line is output that should go into the response stream.

Comment: gallery object is in foreach iteration and it is not null. Already i am getting compilation error. Not runtime error.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code then? If you do not have any html inside the loop before the @gallery, then the @ should be omitted and you should just write gallery.

Comment: Any what is the compilation error? That kind of information would be really relevant information to put in your question in the first place.

Comment: You are greattt yes it is exactly interpreting "(" and ")" characters as a code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(@{Model.gallery.Images.Count} images)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing the Model part in your first statement

```
(@Model.gallery.Images.Count images )
```